# How to upload new skin on dnn 05.06.03

Tags: skinning, dotnetnuke-5

I have a website which was initially made on DNN 4.(??).(??) hosted on win server 2003
Recently I installed a new server, Win server 2008R2, and I migrated the site on this server, and upgraded up to dnn 05.06.03. Initially I was trying to update to latest 6..., but that had problem with HTML module (which is used extensively by the site), so I stick with latest 5.xx.xx, which proved to work ok.

But with 05.06.03 I have another problem - it seems it is broken on upload skin module. I was trying to upload new skins from host menu, but when I click on link Upload Skin, nothing happens.

I was trying in IE9, FF 6.0.2 and Chrome 13.0.782.220 (latest), but all seems to act the same - nothing, nada!

The command attached to the link is

```
<a title="Upload Skin" class="CommandButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr327$HostSettings$cmdUploadSkin$ctl01','')">Upload Skin</a>
```

Any idea what can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the skin in an alternate way, you can FTP the skin zip installer to /Install/Skin and then browse to  (yourwebsite)/install/install.aspx?mode=installresources

Regarding why the regular skin upload does not work, there could be some clues on the DNN's Event Log.